# Are there any uncredited cameos in The World's End?

Tags: cameo, the-worlds-end

Hot Fuzz featured at least [two big names in uncredited cameos](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425112/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) (Peter Jackson as the guy in the Santa suit who stabbed Nicholas Angel in a flashback sequence, and Cate Blanchett as Angel's ex-girlfriend, Jannine).

I was hoping for more of the same in The World's End, but didn't spot any when I saw the film, and haven't read of any either. Are there any I've missed?

Comment: I don't have any proof whatsoever of this, but I could swear that Ben Whishaw was the leader of the "AA(?)" group at the beginning of the film. You never get to see the front of his face, but you kind of get a side view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this interview](http://www.contactmusic.com/news/edgar-wright-yahoo-the-world-end_3686961) with Edgar Wright, there is indeed one surprise cameo in the film - but as of yet the name has not been revealed.

OK - having seen the film, there are a couple of 'guest spots' - but if we are talking uncredited cameos then Pierce Brosnan would have to rank up there ;)

Rafe Spall is also in there, but I doubt he ranks as a 'big' cameo.

Comment: I have seen the movie so who is the surprise cameo?

Answer (score 3):

Mark Heap from Spaced is in there and I'm pretty sure I saw Julia Deakin too, also from Spaced

Comment: Have you seen the film already, Peter?

Comment: That wasn't me who downvoted you BTW :) I'm exited to hear of Mark and Julia's involvement!